# How to exclude object attributes from REST API response?

Tags: soql, rest-api

My app performs the following SOQL query over REST API:

```
SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE IsClosed=True
```

Instead of just returning the Id for each opportunity, the result is:

```
{
  "attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Opportunity/<OPP_ID>"},
  "Id":"<OPP_ID>"
}
```

As you can see, most of the data of the result is not needed, and just uses more bandwidth. Is there a way to exclude the `attributes` field from the result?

Comment: This metadata is necessary for subsequent deserialization or RESTful traversal of the object graph. Is there any concern other than bandwidth?

Comment: @bigassforce no, bandwidth is my only concern. Also, our code doesn't need the metadata.

Comment: it might seem like ceremony but is there by design :-) best leave alone.

Comment: Well if that's "by design", then it's a bad design and there shall be a parameter to exclude this overhead. Now, this is is less bad than one may think, because the request is compressed (gzip). So repeating over and over the very same string is not going to consume more space (but of course the Id which is unique).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no.

Longer answer, not using the standard REST API.

You could write your own REST API for the objects you care about using [`@RestResource`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm) classes, but would you really want to? It's probably not worth it for the sake of ~100 bytes per record unless you are extremely bandwidth constrained.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear, it's not 100 per request - it's per record. If a request returns 2k records, it's 200k additional data, which in my case is more than 80% of the data.

Comment: @Tzach That was a typo on my part. My point still stands though, whilst 80% of the data is a lot, is 200kB really worth worrying about? If it is for your use-case, then you need to start looking at writing your own `@RestResource` classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @HttpPost
    global static void testApi(String arg) {

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [select ID FROM Opportunity WHERE isClosed = true];
        List<String> ids = new List<String>();
        for(Opportunity id : oppList){
            ids.add(id);
        }
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(ids));
}
```